# Insert Dynamic HTML content for Electronic Catalogue - Magazine

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am making an electronic book(magazine). But i have 200 pages(in jpg format). So, in order to avoid writing the same line code for 200 pages i want to find out how to do it with javascript and php.

My HTML code for every page in the ebook is :

```
<div id="page" style="background-image:url(img/2014/image-001.jpg);"></div>
```

My javascript function that makes the change/add is :

```
function myBook(i) 
        {
            var x = document.getElementById("page");

            if (x.hasAttribute("style")) 
            {
                i++;
                x.setAttribute("style", "background-image:url(img/2014/image-00" + i + ".jpg");
            }
        }
```

My php code that calls myBook() function is this :

```
<?php 
    for ($x = 0; $x < 200; $x++) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">myBook($i)</script>'; 
    }
?>
```

All i want is to add(+1) a number to the HTML  element in order to generate the correct jpg file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a typo there, fix it to: x.setAttribute("style", "background-image:url(img/2014/image-00" + i + ".jpg");

Comment: True, but this was just a typo mistake not the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
    for ($x = 0; $x < 200; $x++)
    {
        $a = (String) $x;
        if (strlen($a)<3)
        {
            for($y = 3 - strlen($a); $y > 0; $y--)
            {
                $a = '0' . $a;
            }
        }
        echo '<div id="page" style="background-image:url(img/2014/image-' . $a . '.jpg);"></div>';
    }
?>
```

I think this may do what you wish. Hope it helps !

Comment: It works but i am facing a problem. Some pages can't be load and sometimes when you tour the catalogue the page can't be load. So am i obliged in the end to write 200 line codes or is there some other thoughts. I put the javascript code in external file so the html can load properly. Thanks again!

Comment: You are trying to do a one pager right? one page with 200images displaying as you scroll down?

Comment: I made an eBook there is no scrolling, just a book(every page is a jpg file). When the page is loaded(i am working offline) the book loads properly but then when i am taking a tour through pages some of them are not displayed.

Comment: I write 200 lines of html code to test if everything is ok, but i face the same problem. Does not diplay all pages and when i tour back the catalogue there is a random display of pictures. It looks like that the pictures can't load. So my question is whether this ebook can work cause i'm frustrated.

Comment: Could you identify which images where not displayed? Maybe their name don't match the url given.

Comment: Firebug is showing this error : Image corrupt or truncated: http://localhost//img/2014/image-070.jpg , till the last(200) image. But there are the first 10 pages only displaying. I am using the turn.js library and i think that can't load all images due to cache memmory.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
$a = (String) $x;
if (strlen($a)<3)
{
for($y = 3 - strlen($a); $y > 0; $y--)
{
$a = '0' . $a;
}
}
```

you can write

```
$a = str_pad($x,3,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
```